# Do remote files leave open files?

Tags: snakemake

I've got a workflow that uses a slightly customized S3 RemoteProvider and I suspect that it's hitting strange filesystem errors due to hitting our ulimit on the number of files.  Does anyone know if RemoteProvider objects leave a hanging file object for each file in the workflow?

Comment: FWIW, I eventually end up with a `ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()` in botocore, which based on other SO threads is why I think this is a ulimit issue.

Comment: Snakemake can generate a lot of files in a `.snakemake` hidden subfolder.